# remove unwanted characters and evaluate remaining in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to be able to evaluate a formula in a cell (in excel) that has descriptions inbetween the values.
For example, I'll have 3hrs*2ppl + 4 in the cell, and I'll want to evaluate it in another cell to return the numerical answer (eg. 10) in this case.

Can anyone help me?

Ps. I don't know much about Visual Basic but can create the macro if the code is already written for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this vba function. It will only work for the four basic operations.

```
 Function sEvalFormula(sInput As String) As String
Dim lLoop As Long, sSpecialChars As String, sTemp As String

sSpecialChars = "0123456789-+*/()=."


For lLoop = 1 To Len(sInput)
    If InStr(sSpecialChars, Mid(sInput, lLoop, 1)) > 0 Then sTemp = sTemp & Mid(sInput, lLoop, 1)
Next

sEvalFormula = Evaluate(sTemp)


End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

First, enter the following **UDF** in a standard module:

```
Public Function evall(s As String) As Variant
    l = Len(s)
    s2 = ""
    For i = 1 To l
        ch = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If ch Like "[a-z]" Then
        Else
            s2 = s2 & ch
        End If
    Next i
    evall = Evaluate(s2)
End Function
```

So if **A1** contains:

3hrs*2ppl + 4

then

```
=evall(A1)
```

will display **10**

This **UDF** discards lower case letters and evaluates the remaining expression.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is by using regular expressions (Regex).  See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22542834/2521004) for more information on what the patterns mean.

Also, make sure you add ”Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5″ as  reference to your VBA module (see this [link](http://www.macrostash.com/2011/10/08/simple-regular-expression-tutorial-for-excel-vba/) for how to do that).

I'm passing in a cell address, stripping out any letters, and then evaluating the function.

```
Function RegExpReplace(cell As Range, _
        Optional ByVal IsGlobal As Boolean = True, _
        Optional ByVal IsCaseSensitive As Boolean = True) As Variant

    'Declaring the object
    Dim objRegExp As Object

    'Initializing an Instance
    Set objRegExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    'Setting the Properties
    objRegExp.Global = IsGlobal
    objRegExp.pattern = "[a-zA-Z]"
    objRegExp.IgnoreCase = Not IsCaseSensitive

    'Execute the Replace Method
    RegExpReplace = Evaluate(objRegExp.Replace(cell.Text, ""))
End Function
```

---

In Cell `B1` enter this formula: `=RegExpReplace(A1)`

---

Results:

[image]